# Advice on setting up private site

Tags: plugins, login, membership, authentication, private

I've developed a wordpress site which is only to be made available to around 30 people, whose email addresses I have in a spreadsheet. I want to allow these people to be able to register/login and then set their own password. What would be the best process for going about this? Thank you for any answers!

Comment: I have not used this plugin but http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-users-from-csv/ seems like a good start

Comment: What do you mean by 'Available'? Do you want all your content hidden by everyone but those 30 people?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is just to create accounts for every people from spreadsheet. You can use code provided [here](http://www.joshuawinn.com/create-a-new-wordpress-admin-user-from-php/) but generating random passwords instead and sending a mail to each registered user with their information and alerting them to change their passwords on first login.

Comment: So they would just be set up as basic subscribers, then I would set the WP site to be private to subscribers only?

Comment: Please provide code, rather than linking to resources. The link could die, and then your answer is no longer helpful.

Comment: @bsod99 you could use the members only plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/

Comment: @bsod99 - that plugin was last updated in 2008.... it's no longer supported.